# How does AngularJS respond to a form value being updated in Javascript?

Tags: angularjs

I don't use Angular regularly, but I understand that one of the key features is that when data is updated on a form element, it is automatically updated in the model.

If you are instead using a library like jQuery, you must manually attach an event to the form input that updates the model when it is changed, as in `$('#myInput').on('change', updateModel);`

Although the above handler will be fired when myInput is changed by the user, it will not be fired if myInput is changed by Javascript code such as `$('#myInput').val('hello world');`

My question is, how does Angular know when a form input is changed in Javascript code?

Comment: Changed how? A short code snippet would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular applies a scope digest every time it's needed (by an Angular function) during which it checks the states of all the scope variables, including the models used, of course.

If you modify some of those variables manually, using JavaScript, jQuery, etc... Angular will not know that the changes have occured and you need to tell it so either by doing `$scope.$apply()` or by wrapping the code block in a `$timeout` callback (these are the most commonly used methods).

If you don't do it manually, you'd have to wait for some (if any) other Angular event to trigger the digest cycle, which is never good.

See this example, note how nothing happens when you just update the value, but you need to do it manually (`ng-click` does it) in order for DOM to update:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.ourValue = 'Initial Value';
  window.exposedFunc = function(v, digest) {
    $scope.ourValue = v;
    if (digest) {
      $scope.$apply();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  
  <button onclick="exposedFunc('First Button Value')">Update Value - No Digest</button>
  <button onclick="exposedFunc('Second Button Value', true)">Update Value - Force Digest</button>
  <button ng-click="">Force Digest only</button>
  <p>{{ourValue}}</p>
</div>
```

---

Here's a super simple example of binding using keyup event. It should be enough to get you started on your projects:

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
function handleChange(v) {
  res.textContent = v;
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="handleChange(this.value)" type="text" value="Initial value" />
<p id="r">No binding yet</p>
```

Comment: I see.  I'm actually not using Angular on this project.  However, I'm using some other Javascript library which updates form values and I was wondering how to make my Javascript automatically respond to the form being updated by the Javascript.  I thought that this is what Angular does, but apparently, I am mistaken.

Comment: Angular does it for its own variables (scope variables), not for everything. Let me write you a simple plain JS example of how you can do it.